# How to get an exact one of python iterator?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, io

I was reading a super big csv file(10G) using pandas, and read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize) return me an iterator (assum it names 'reader'). And now I want to get an exact chunk because I just want a certain few of lines(for example, the csv file I read has 1000000000 lines, and I want to get number 50000000 line and 1000 lines after it), what should I do except tranverse the iterator until it reaches the chunk I want?

Here is my former code:

```
def get_lines_by_chunk(file_name, line_beg, line_end, chunk_size=-1):
func_name = 'get_lines_by_chunk'
line_no = get_file_line_no(file_name)

if chunk_size < 0:
    chunk_size = get_chunk_size(line_no, line_beg, line_end)

reader = pd.read_csv(file_name, chunksize=chunk_size)
data = pd.DataFrame({})

flag = 0

for chunk in reader:
    line_before = flag * chunk_size
    flag = flag + 1
    line_after = flag * chunk_size
    if line_beg >= line_before and line_beg <= line_after:
        if line_end >= line_after:
            temp = chunk[line_beg - line_before : chunk_size]
            data = pd.concat([data, temp], ignore_index=True)
        else:
            temp = chunk[line_beg - line_before : line_end - line_before]
            data = pd.concat([data, temp], ignore_index=True)
            return data
    elif line_end <= line_after and line_end >= line_before:
        temp = chunk[0 : line_end - line_before]
        data = pd.concat([data, temp], ignore_index=True)
        return data
    elif line_beg < line_before and line_end > line_after:
        temp = chunk[0 : chunk_size]
        data = pd.concat([data, temp], ignore_index=True)

return data
```

Comment: can't you just do `df = pd.read_csv(file_name, skiprows=50000000, nrows=1000)`?

Comment: oh...it seems works, I am new to pandas..

Comment: The title *"How to get an exact one of python iterator?*" doesn't make any sense to me. Can you reword it?

Comment: I mean pandas.read_csv return an iterator 'i' when assign it a chunksize, and I want i.next().next().next()... (for example 500 number of next) without 500 iterations but a direct getting operation like an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to read your CSV file with differently-sized chunks you can use `iterator=True`:

Assuming we have a 1000rows DF (see in setup section for how it's been generated)

```
In [103]: reader = pd.read_csv(fn, iterator=True)

In [104]: reader.get_chunk(5)
Out[104]:
   a   b
0  1   8
1  2  28
2  3  85
3  4  56
4  5  29

In [105]: reader.get_chunk(3)
Out[105]:
   a   b
5  6  55
6  7  16
7  8  96
```

NOTE: `get_chunk` can't skip data, it will continuously read data with specified chunk sizes

if you want to read only the rows 100 - 110:

```
In [106]: cols = pd.read_csv(fn, nrows=1).columns.tolist()

In [107]: cols
Out[107]: ['a', 'b']

In [109]: pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, skiprows=100, nrows=10, names=cols)
Out[109]:
     a   b
0  100  52
1  101  15
2  102  74
3  103  10
4  104  35
5  105  73
6  106  48
7  107  49
8  108   1
9  109  56
```

But if you can use HDF5 format - it will be much easier and faster:

let's save it as HDF5 first :

```
In [110]: df.to_hdf('c:/temp/test.h5', 'mydf', format='t', data_columns=True, compression='blosc', complevel=9)
```

now we can read it by index positions as follows:

```
In [113]: pd.read_hdf('c:/temp/test.h5', 'mydf', start=99, stop=109)
Out[113]:
       a   b
99   100  52
100  101  15
101  102  74
102  103  10
103  104  35
104  105  73
105  106  48
106  107  49
107  108   1
108  109  56
```

or querying (SQL like):

```
In [115]: pd.read_hdf('c:/temp/test.h5', 'mydf', where="a >= 100 and a <= 110")
Out[115]:
       a   b
99   100  52
100  101  15
101  102  74
102  103  10
103  104  35
104  105  73
105  106  48
106  107  49
107  108   1
108  109  56
109  110  23
```

Setup:

```
In [99]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(1, 1001), 'b':np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)})

In [100]: fn = r'C:\Temp\test.csv'

In [101]: df.to_csv(fn, index=False)

In [102]: df.shape
Out[102]: (1000, 2)
```

Comment: thanks, and by the way do you know how pandas.read_csv(skiprows=skiprows) works? Does it use a C engine?

Comment: @flyingrose, yes, it should use C engine, unless it gives you a warning that C engine can't be used because of "<reason>"...

Comment: but how it works? by which way it just ignores first few lines? reading by chunk?

Comment: @flyingrose, sorry i don't understand... Could you open a new question with a small reproducible example (including small sample data set)?